# change volume of a handled soundfx in cocos2d

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, volume, handle

```
int __sfxHandle;
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]stopEffect:__sfxHandle];
```

by this way I can stop the specified sound via its handle number.
but how can I do something like this ?
somethig like :
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]setVolumeEffect:.5f Handler:__sfxHandle];

possible ?

Comment: not with simpleaudioengine. Normally you can't change an effects volume but all of the effects playing on a specific channel which has a volume property. Not sure how CD manages channels though.

Comment: any other sound engine can do it ?
IOS can.as we see in garageband and similar apps

Comment: ObjectAL is the engine i used. Easier to use imho. Still you'll need a channel to change volume of all sounds played on that channel but it's easier to create and manage channels.